# automatic parallelization

Tags: multithreading, multicore

I want automatically parallelize sequential program in thread level to run on multi-core
processors.
I dont know use lvm or openIMPACT or other compilers.can you help me in this topic?

Comment: there's very little about parallelization that comes automatically...more details please?

Comment: I want split a program into multiple partition and assign each partition to a thread and run threads with pipeline model. of course with concern on dependency between instructions of program.

Comment: Forget about dependency of instructions, a more fundamental problem is data dependency. Do you have some large set of data that you can easily partition into slices, and have processed separately without the threads depending on each others data? If you do, then chances are you might be able to do some automatic parallelization (Such as OMP, VC++ parallel_For). What language is this in?

Comment: I have a sequential program without large set of data but control and data dependency between basic blocks is important. I dont have any force in select special language.

Comment: What language is your program written in?

Answer (score 0):

You want to split your sequential program into a pipeline of tasks that communicate via data streams. Assuming for example a C or C++ program, you will need to manually rewrite the application into a network of parallel tasks. There are various APIs to help you write the tasks and communication. The formal model that fits nicely with this is that of [Kahn Process Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahn_process_networks) (KPN).

Obviously, the real challenge is rewriting your code to expose all communication into explicit data streams. This can be a lot of work depending on the application.

For implementation, OpenMP has some support for task parallelism. Have a look at the [vfTasks library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vftasks/) (C/C++) for an efficient streaming API that you can easliy port to whatever architecture you have in mind. (Disclaimer: I am one of the authors).